# monotonicity of a function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, monotone-functions

Let $g(x,y)$ be a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, such that $g$ is decreasing with respect to $x$ and decreasing with respect to $y$.
and let  $f(x,y)$ be a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, such that $f$ is decreasing with respect to $x$ and decreasing with respect to $y$

what is the monocity of $f(g(x,y),y)$ with respt to $y$ ?

Can we deduce that  $f(g(x,y),y)$ is increasing with respect to $y$ as a composition of two decreasing functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so :

take $g(x,y)=-x-y$ and $f(x,y)=-x - 2y$, then you have $$f(g(x,y),y)=x+y-2y=x-y$$ which is decreasing with respect to $y$.